# Quick 'n' dirty job deferment

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, error-handling, cfml, coldfusion-10

I'm just after some sanity checking of this code:

```
public struct function defer(required function job, function onSuccess, function onFailure, function onError, function onTerminate){
    var threadId = "deferredThread_#createUuid()#";

    local[threadId] = "";

    try {
        cfthread.status = "Running";
        thread name=threadId action="run" attributecollection=arguments {
            try {
                successData.result = job();
                cfthread.status = "Completed";
                if (structKeyExists(attributes, "onSuccess")){
                    onSuccess(successData);
                }
            } catch (any e){
                cfthread.status = "Failed";
                if (structKeyExists(attributes, "onFailure")){
                    onFailure(e);
                }else{
                    rethrow;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (any e){
        cfthread.status = "Errored";
        if (structKeyExists(arguments, "onError")){
            onError(e);
        }else{
            rethrow;
        }
    }
    return {
        getStatus = function(){
            return cfthread.status;
        },
        getThreadId = function(){
            return threadId;
        },
        terminate = function(){
            if (cfthread.status == "Running"){
                thread name=threadId action="terminate";
                cfthread.status = "Terminated";
                if (isDefined("onTerminate")){
                    onTerminate();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Blog article about it: "[Threads, callbacks, closure and a pub](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/threads-callbacks-closures-and-pub.html)", and [tests and stuff on Github](https://github.com/adamcameroncoldfusion/scratch/tree/master/cflib/defer).

Here is a summary of that, copied from the article, and edited for length & situation:

> A week or so ago I encountered a feature proposition for CFML which
>   was adding closure callback support to the following
>   functions/operations so they can be processed natively in the
>   background (non-blocking) and then call back when done:
>
> FileRead FileWrite etc
>
> Basically any operation that can block a network or local resource. 
>   Imagine doing this:

```
fileRead( file, function(contents){
    // process file here in the background once it is read.
});
```

> This is a reasonable idea in general, but I don't think the suggested
>   approach is very good as it's too focused on specific pain points.
>
> My suggested approach would be more all-encompassing. Why limit this
>   functionality to a subset of predetermined built-in functions? What
>   about other built-in operations that might be slow, but otherwise
>   doesn't need to interact with the rest of the code subsequent to it in
>   the request? What about custom code that is similar? It makes little
>   sense to me to "hard-code" this sort of behaviour to specific
>   operations, to me.
>
> A better solution would be to provide a general mechanism that can be
>   used by any code to background-thread its execution, and fire
>   callbacks on completion, failure etc, so as to kick off the next
>   process, or flag-up that the process has completed.
>
> Then it occurred to me that I thought I could knock a solution out to
>   this using a single function. Not a very complete solution, but a
>   solution nevertheless.